# file_exists included files

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a file exists from within an included file but not sure what the path would be.

Let a draw up the directory structure:

```
/public_html/
  index.php
  images/pics/pic1.jpg
  subdir1/somefile1.php
  subdir2/somefile2.php
  shared/sharecodefile.php (file of functions that shared amoung all files)
```

Firstly in index.php, when i do :

```
file_exists("images/pics/pic1.jpg")
```

This works. However, when including sharecodefile.php. i'm a bit lost as to what dir this file now assumes as it's current dir. if I include this file in index.php,

```
file_exists("images/pics/pic1.jpg")
```

This does not work. I've tried :

```
file_exists("./images/pics/pic1.jpg"); 
file_exists("../images/pics/pic1.jpg");
file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."images/pics/pic1.jpg");
file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/pics/pic1.jpg");
```

None seems to work.
To make things worse, I also need to include sharecodefile.php in the other files `somefile1.php` + `somefile2.php`

Any pointers / explanation of what to do will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you just execute the sharecodefile.php whats happends? it found the file in some of your tries?

Comment: 0
down vote
I once again came across this problem...

I think the last time i just reverted to fopen or something else to check if the image exists After another round of Googling on this... i found that the public_html folder on our ISP server is actually a symlink...

I suspect this to be the problem. Have not yet found solution. Will revert back to fopen again as it seems PHP yet to find a solution to file_exists and symlinks. Some bug reports on the issue going back to 2007.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this code:

```
define( "PATH_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__) . "/");
```

in `index.php` (assuming that you're including everything from index.php), than you'll just use:

```
file_exists( PATH_ROOT . 'images/pics/pic1.jpg');
```

And of course if you need it to work directly from  `sharedcodefile.php` you may do this:

```
file_exists( dirname( __FILE__) . '/../images/pics/pic1.jpg');
```

Here're few words on [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Answer (score 0):

By default I believe `shared/sharecodefile.php` will assume any paths are relative to the executing script (`index.php`), so simply:

```
file_exists('images/pics/pic1.jpg');
```

should still work.

But it sounds like you need the code to be more portable, and work regardless of where the file is included. In which case, you probably want any paths to be relative to `shared/sharecodefile.php`.

To do this, try:

```
file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/../images/pics/pic1.jpg');
```

Or you could opt for an absolute path from the site root:

```
file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/pics/pic1.jpg');
```

**Edit:** I just noticed you said `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` wasn't working for you. I'm not sure why, it worked in my tests.